# Changing Xxs in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am working with IntelliJ Idea and I need to change the **-Xxs**. Where should I change it from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For IDEA itself or for your app? If the first, see reply from Tomasz. If the latter, edit the **VM options** in the Run/Debug configuration.

Answer (score 0):

`idea.vmoptions` file under `/bin` in IntelliJ installation directory.